# How to post this kind of form using PHP Curl?

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm trying to post this kind of post using PHP curl, but I have no idea of how to post it, because this one is different than the ones  I'm used to post.

```
 -----------------------------109944606510290837051636792786
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cliente[id]"

    572572
    -----------------------------109944606510290837051636792786
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cliente[documento1]"

    154.574.284-78
    -----------------------------109944606510290837051636792786
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gender[sexo]"

    feminino
    -----------------------------109944606510290837051636792786
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cliente[email]"

    email@example.com
    -----------------------------109944606510290837051636792786
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cliente[nome1]"

    Ashley
    -----------------------------109944606510290837051636792786
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cliente[nome2]"

    Ivy
    -----------------------------109944606510290837051636792786
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="endereco[cep]"

    03164-100
    -----------------------------109944606510290837051636792786
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="endereco[endereco]"

    Rua Example
    -----------------------------109944606510290837051636792786
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="endereco[numero]"

    123
```

I tried doing like this, but didn't work:

```
 // Post Adicionar ao Carrinho
               $link = "https://www.example.com.br/identificacao/"; 
                $post = "
                -----------------------------109944606510290837051636792786
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cliente[id]"

572572
-----------------------------109944606510290837051636792786
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cliente[documento1]"

154.574.284-78
...... "; 
                $s = _curl($link,$post,$cookie);
```

I can post with no problems forms like this one:

```
$post = "comprar%5Bquantidade%5D=1&id_alias=135&client%5Bid_produto%5D=90881&comprar%5Bvariacao%5D=94402";
```

But I don't know what kind of form is that one ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example data you've posted is encoded as `multipart/form-data`. In order to make curl post the data in this format you need to feed `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` an array. [See Documentation](http://php.net/curl_setopt)

Assuming that that is where your `$post` variable is going the following should produce the desired POST:

```
$post = array(
    'cliente[id]' => '572572',
    'cliente[documento1]' => '154.574.284-78',
    ...
);

$s = _curl($link,$post,$cookie);
```